How to integrating Morefun(Mf919) POS SDK with Flutter
I am trying to integrate Morefun(Mf919) POS SDK with Flutter using Java code but the POS device is not connected and throws error:
Error: Device service connection failed, please try again later.
    public void bindDeviceService() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setPackage(SERVICE_ACTION);
            intent.setAction(SERVICE_PACKAGE);
            ServiceConnection connection = this.connection;
            Log.e(TAG,"======ServiceConnection====== connection:" + connection);
            _context.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "======bindDeviceService======", e);
        }
    }
    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            deviceServiceEngine = null;
            Log.e(TAG, "======onServiceDisconnected======");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.e(TAG, "======Start Service Connection======");
            deviceServiceEngine = DeviceServiceEngine.Stub.asInterface(service);
            Log.d(TAG, "======onServiceConnected======");

            try {
                reset();
                initDevices();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


